# passar dados do input para a tabela do banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql, python

Galera me ajuda ai, estou criando um gerenciador de usuários com sistema de level.
porem não estou conseguindo passar um valor da variavel definido pelo **input()** para o **INSERT**.
por favor me ajudem.

code:

```
def registrar_usuario():

    print("id:")
    id_bd = input()

    print("level:")
    level_bd = input()

    print("usuario:")
    usuario_bd = input()

    print("senha:")
    senha_bd = input()

    criar_usuarios = " INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `level`, `usuario`, `senha`) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s) (id_bd, level_bd, usuario_bd, senha_bd) "
    banco_de_dados.execute(criar_usuarios)
```

Comment: Olá Ghost Designer, qual é a mensagem de erro que retorna?

Comment: Essa aqui amigo: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s) (id_bd, level_bd, usuario_bd, senha_bd)' at line 1

Comment: Tenta desta forma:

criar_usuarios = "INSERT INTO usuarios ('id', 'level', 'usuario', 'senha') VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s) (id_bd, level_bd, usuario_bd, senha_bd)"

Comment: Nao foi o mesmo erro ocorreu.

Comment: Olá Ghost, Testei aqui o código da minha resposta e funcionou certinho. Dica: Criar um arquivo chamado teste_insert.py e colar o código da minha resposta. Para fazer funcionar eu utilizei o XAMP e MySQL conector. No XAMP cria um banco igual ao da minha resposta. No "user" coloca root e a senha deixa em branco. Fazendo isto vai dar certo, depois basta adaptar o código para fazer o que você precisa. Abraço!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu `INSERT` tem um espaço extra no início da string. No nome da tabela não deve ter aspas. Além disto você está usando crase onde deveria ser aspas simples. Veja este exemplo e compare!

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```